# Spring boot not scanning components and configurations

Tags: spring-boot, autowired

I have a multi-module project:

```
TOP_LEVEL
|-> core
|-> assetManager
'-> requestManager
```

So, I have a core module which has Application class in the core module.

In my assetManger build.gradle I `compile(project(:core))`

The application main class is in package : `com.test.companydomain.core` of the core module.
This Application class is annotated with

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.test.companydomain"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.test.companydomain", "com.test.companydomain.assetManager"})
@EnableJpaRepositories
class Application {

}
```

There is a class ClientUtils in assetManager module in the package : `com.test.domain.assetManager.server.common.utils;`

annotated with :

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@Component("clientUtils")
```

There are beans that I am creating in this class and It uses other configuration classes for autowiring and creating beans.

The beans are not getting generated as of now from this ClientUtils class.

What can be a possible issue with this?

The error i see is

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

```
Field locationService in com.test.companydomain.assetManager.server.vendor.converter.ExternalVendorPojoConversionHelper required a bean of type 
'com.test.companydomain.assetManager.server.common.utils.client.LocationService' that could not be found.
```

This class LocationService is also annotated with @Component for spring to create its bean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your application , the main class is present in the package `com.test.companydomain.core` and by default springboot scans all classes and packages under the current package of the main application for autowiring beans. So , you have provided the annotation `@ComponentScan` to explicitly tell spring to scan other packages as well.But your `util` class is in the package `com.test.domain.assetManager.server.common.utils` , which is not included in the `@ComponentScan` annotation, so it is not taken up for component scanning.

Could you try adding the package com.test.domain to the component scan in main class like :

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.test.companydomain","com.test.domain"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.test.companydomain", "com.test.companydomain.assetManager","com.test.domain"})
@EnableJpaRepositories
class Application {

}
```

Comment: I figured that out. I don't know why but I had to create a named bean and that solved  my problem. There were no logs for this error. Is there a way to identify such issues in debugging. I could not find logs even if I had given debug: true for the application

Comment: However, what you said is also right. But in this case, everything in the com.test.companydomain will be picked up even if they are in different modules. Their group id is same and that is what i had provided. It works.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Spring Boot, you should consider using `@SpringBootApplication` annotation and configure base packages to scan with [`scanBasePackages`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html#scanBasePackages--) instead of `@ComponentScan`:

```
package com.test.companydomain.core;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.test.companydomain")
@EntityScan({"com.test.companydomain", "com.test.companydomain.assetManager"})
public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

By default, Spring Boot scans only package of the class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` and its sub-packages.

Also, [`@Configuration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) is meta-annotated with `@Component`, so `@Configuration` classes are candidates for component scanning and should not be explicitly annotated with `@Component`:

```
package com.test.domain.assetManager.server.common.utils;

@Configuration
public class ClientUtils {

  @Autowired
  private ClientProperties properties;

  @Bean
  public TestClient testClient() {
    return new TestClient(properties); //example
  }
}
```

and

```
package com.test.companydomain.assetManager.server.common.utils.client;

@Component
public class LocationService {
  //...
}
```